# managed array of pointers in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, pointers, managed

I have a trouble creating managed array of pointers.

I've tried

```
public unsafe class Car
{
    public int speed;

    public Car()
    {
        speed = 0;
    }

    public Car(int speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new Car[10]; // 1st way
        fixed(Car* ptr = arr)
        {}

        Car* arr = stackalloc Car[10]; // 2nd way
    }
}
```

After both tries I get the same error: "Impossible to get adress or size or define a pointer of managed type".
Does somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and why do you think pointers are the way to solve your problem?

Comment: This is a task from a lab in the university, There is a class Car and I need to create array of 10 pointers.

Comment: You've been specifically asked to use pointers?

Comment: Yes, there are a few tasks in a row. Write a definition of a function which returns long and gets int. Change this task as if the func was a member of a class Car. Define array of 10 pointers of class Car.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as [C# specs](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc) say:

> Unlike references (values of reference types), pointers are not
> tracked by the garbage collector—the garbage collector has no
> knowledge of pointers and the data to which they point.
>
> For this
> reason a pointer is not permitted to point to a reference or to a
> struct that contains references, and the referent type of a pointer
> must be an unmanaged-type. An unmanaged-type is any type that isn’t a
> reference-type and doesn’t contain reference-type fields at any level
> of nesting. In other words, an unmanaged-type is one of the following:
>
> sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float,
> double, decimal, or bool.
>
> Any enum-type.
>
> Any pointer-type. Any user-defined struct-type that contains fields of unmanaged-types only.

Comment: I got it, so I can't define a pointer of managed class? There's no way to fix it?